# (Sequential) weighted sampling

Tags: matlab, bayesian, random, markov-chains

I need to figure out the total path (A to Z) followed by an agent through a squared-element grid. Each grid element has a probability density function *Delta* assigned to it that represents the probable direction (0-360) that the agent might take when stepping over it.

So, say that when agent is in grid cell *A*, I sample the corresponding directions pdf *Delta_A* and I get the value *delta_A*. Agent then moves in that direction *delta* and arrives to a neighbor grid cell in the next step *B*.

To find out next direction, I'll sample the pdf *Delta_B*, but here I want the value *delta_B* to receive more weight than the other values in *Delta_B*. Is there a methodology for that?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume the possible directions are a finite set. Take a look at [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/randsample.html) and specially its fourth argument (`w`)

Comment: Yes, they're a finite set. Thanks Luis.